# read a file to EOF in shell/bash in while loop pipe seperated - shell script

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I would like to read a file to EOF which has multiple sql queries separated by pipe or double pipe. Choosing pipe because tab, \n and space are could already be present in queries. The queries can span to multiple lines. Each query needs to be read into a variable and inside the while loop, I would like to run a command/SQL query on a DB using that querystring variable. The loop has to do this for all querystrings created from the file.

Example file Contents:

```
select * from blah;||select column from table1;||select column7 from table4;EOF
```

This is my script so far:

```
while IFS=$'||' read -r querystring
do
 run some shell command on ${querystring} 
done < myqueryfile.sql
```

This is how much I got so far. thoughts/comments appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If sql file contains some sentences with multiple lines like:

```
select *
from blah;||
select column
from table1;||
select column7
from table4;
```

You could use gawk/awk to isolate sentence blocks with separation pipes in other line. This produce an output easy to process:

```
gawk -v RS="[|][|]" -v ORS="\n||\n" '{ print $0}' file | while read -r line
do 
  if [ "$line" == "||" ]; then
    run some shell command on "$sentence"
    sentence=""
  else    
    sentence=$sentence"\n"$line
  fi
done
```

No temp files are required ;-)

Comment: I like what you are doing. What is the content of $sentence? How is $ sentence being populated? will the loop run until all SQL statements are executed individually in the "if" statement?

Comment: $sentence stores each sql statement from file. Every separation pipes resets $sentence after execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk:

```
/tmp ❯❯❯ cat /tmp/a                                                                                                                                                                                              ⏎
select * from blah;||select column from table1;||select column7 from table4
/tmp ❯❯❯ awk 'BEGIN {FS="[|][|]"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "run some shell command on %s\n",$i}' /tmp/a
run some shell command on select * from blah;
run some shell command on select column from table1;
run some shell command on select column7 from table4
/tmp ❯❯❯ awk 'BEGIN {FS="[|][|]"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "run some shell command on %s\n",$i}' /tmp/a |sh -
```